# Twitter follower count as HTTP/HTTPS JSON endpoint

Tags: json, twitter, endpoint

Is there a way to get a Twitter user's follower count as an HTTP/HTTPS endpoint?

The output has to be in a JSON format and respect the following syntax {"number":1234}.

I found this article on Twitter, but I'm not familiar with JSON.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-ids

I need the output of the number for a clock that should show the current follower count.

I would appreciate your help.

Best, C

Comment: If you look at the example request you will find a sample to that endpoint with the user ID as a query parameter. Of course you can't just make a request without authentication. I suggest you start with the following https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/getting-access-to-the-twitter-api

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That means it's a bit more complicated than I thought. Do you think there is another solution to achieve the same goal?